# Using preg_replace on an array

Tags: php, regex, arrays, preg-replace

I have a relatively large array of elements which I want to search for a string and replace any matches. I'm currently trying to do this using `preg_replace` and regular expressions:

```
preg_replace("/\d?\dIPT\.\w/", "IPT", $array);
```

I want to get all values which match either `00IPT.A` or `0IPT.A` (with `0` representing any numerical character and `A` representing any letter) and replace them with `IPT`. However, I'm getting array to string conversion notices. Is there any way to get `preg_replace` to accept an array data source? If not, is there any other way I could achieve this?

The documentation says that `preg_replace` should be able to accept array sources — this is the reason I'm asking.

> The string or an array with strings to search and replace.
>   If subject is an array, then the search and replace is performed on every entry of       subject, and the return value is an array as well.

**The array is multidimensional if that helps (has multiple arrays under one main array).**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`preg_replace` doesn't modify in place. To permanently modify `$array`, you simply need to assign the result of `preg_replace` to it:

```
$array = preg_replace("/\d{1,2}IPT\.\w/", "IPT", $array);
```

works for me.

```
$array = array('00IPT.A', '0IPT.A');
$array = preg_replace("/\d{1,2}IPT\.\w/", "IPT", $array);
var_dump($array);
// output: array(2) { [0]=> string(3) "IPT" [1]=> string(3) "IPT" }
```

Note: the `\d{1,2}` means one or two digits.

If you want to do this to a two-dimensional array, you need to loop through the first dimension:

```
$array = array( array('00IPT.A', 'notmatch'), array('neither', '0IPT.A') );    
foreach ($array as &$row) {
    $row = preg_replace("/\d{1,2}IPT\.\w/", "IPT", $row);
}
var_dump($array);
```

output:

```
array(2) { 
    [0]=> array(2) { 
        [0]=> string(3) "IPT" 
        [1]=> string(8) "notmatch" 
    } 
    [1]=> &array(2) { 
        [0]=> string(7) "neither" 
        [1]=> string(3) "IPT" 
    } 
}
```

Note that you have to loop through each row **by reference** (`&$row`) otherwise the original array will not be modified.

Comment: Would this work on multidimensional arrays though? My arrays are organised like this:

array(4500) {
  [0]=>
  array(19) {
    [0]=>
    string(0) ""
    [1]=>
    string(32) "SNIP"
    [2]=>
    string(0) ""
    [3]=>
    string(0) ""
    [4]=>
    string(0) ""
    [5]=>
    string(0) ""
    [6]=>
    string(0) ""
  }

Comment: And which elements to you want to perform the replacement on? All of them?

Comment: I'd like to replace the values of all elements which match the regex search term. Some arrays after the one I listed include:

string(5) "9IPT.A"
    [4]=>
    string(3) "TEA"
    [5]=>
    string(2) "BT"
    [6]=>
    string(5) "10RC1"
    [7]=>
    string(3) "IRE"
    [8]=>
    string(2) "A3"
    [9]=>
    string(5) "10RC1"

So an example would be leaving 10RC1 untouched but changing 9IPT.A to IPT. Would this be possible?

Answer (score 1):

Your value does not sit in the array as a simple element but as a subset right? Like so?

```
array (
  array ('id' => 45, 'name' => 'peter', 'whatyouarelookingfor' => '5F'),
  array ('id' => 87, 'name' => 'susan', 'whatyouarelookingfor' => '8C'),
  array ('id' => 92, 'name' => 'frank', 'whatyouarelookingfor' => '9R')
)
```

if so:

```
<?php

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
  $array[$key]['whatyouarelookingfor'] =  
    preg_replace("/\d?\dIPT\.\w/", "IPT", $value['whatyouarelookingfor']);
}
```

Or if more elements have this, just go broader:

```
<?php

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
  $array[$key] =  
    preg_replace("/\d?\dIPT\.\w/", "IPT", $value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

your `$array` contains some further arrays.  `preg_replace` works fine with arrays of strings, but not with arrays of arrays [of arrays...] of strings.

Comment: Oh so preg_replace doesn't work with multidimensional arrays? Dam, do you know a way around this then?