# how to use preg_replace with dimensional pattern and replacement in php?

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-replace

This is my code:

```
$search = array 
    (
    array('/iked$/', '/ked$/', '/sed$/', '/hed$/', '/xed$/', '/ated$/', '/ited$/', '/ted$/', '/nded$/', '/red$/', '/zed$/', '/led$/', '/med$/', '/ned$/', '/wed$/', '/ied$/', '/bbed$/', '/nged$/', '/gged$/', '/ged$/', '/cided$/', '/luded$/', '/ded$/', '/eeded$/', '/pped$/', '/ced$/', '/ved$/', '/yed/'),

    array('/ying$/')
);

$replace = array
    (
    array('ike', 'k', 'se', 'h', 'x', 'ate', 'ite', 't', 'nd', 'r', 'z', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'w', 'y', 'b', 'ng', 'g', 'ge', 'cide', 'lude', 'd', 'eed', 'p', 'ce', 've', 'y'),

    array('y')
);

$kd = preg_replace($search, $replace, $_GET['verb2']);
```

I want to convert verb forms into Infinitives, e.g. `worked` to `work`, `studying` to `study`.
Does anyone know why my code doesn't work?

Is there any other solution?

Comment: It seems that multidimensional arrays aren't supported by preg_replace? If you use one-dimensional array, all works fine...

Comment: @AndreMartin try with my answer, you can build your array in my example, but as nevermind says must be one-dimensional. Don't forget check as correct my answer ;-)

Comment: @AndreMartin you solved your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this example and correct your code:

```
<?php

$search = array('/ked$/', '/ying$/');

$replace = array('k', 'y');

$w = preg_replace($search, $replace, 'worked');
$s = preg_replace($search, $replace, 'studying');

print_r($w);
echo '<br>';
print_r($s);

?>
```

If you want have a multidimensional array pattern, see this:

> [Using preg_replace on a array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22553860/3653989)